# Batch Process Test_Bib_Import fails on OLE 1.5.2.1 installation

Tags: kuali

After upgrading to OLE 1.5.2.1 when I try to upload a local MARC .mrc-file via batch process I get the following error:

`Batch process Failed for profile :: Test_Bib_Import`

The same exact file worked fine in OLE 1.5.0-M2

Catalina.out contains the following error:

```
[INFO] org.kuali.ole.batch.impl.OLEBatchProcessAdhocStep - Executing Batch process type :: Bib Import
[ERROR] org.kuali.ole.batch.ingest.BatchProcessBibImport - java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERROR] org.kuali.ole.batch.helper.OLEBatchProcessDataHelper - Error while performing batch process for profile :: Test_Bib_Import
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.kuali.ole.batch.ingest.BatchProcessBibImport.processBatch(BatchProcessBibImport.java:90)
    at org.kuali.ole.batch.impl.AbstractBatchProcess.process(AbstractBatchProcess.java:87)
    at org.kuali.ole.batch.impl.OLEBatchProcessAdhocStep.executeBatch(OLEBatchProcessAdhocStep.java:50)
    at org.kuali.ole.batch.impl.OLEBatchProcessAdhocStep.execute(OLEBatchProcessAdhocStep.java:30)
    at org.kuali.ole.sys.batch.Job.runStep(Job.java:175)
    at org.kuali.ole.sys.batch.Job.execute(Job.java:121)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.kuali.ole.batch.helper.BatchBibImportHelper.processBibMarcRecord(BatchBibImportHelper.java:89)
    at org.kuali.ole.batch.helper.BatchBibImportHelper.processBatch(BatchBibImportHelper.java:70)
    at org.kuali.ole.batch.ingest.BatchProcessBibImport.processBatch(BatchProcessBibImport.java:152)
    at org.kuali.ole.batch.ingest.BatchProcessBibImport.processBatch(BatchProcessBibImport.java:83)
    ... 7 more
[ERROR] org.kuali.ole.batch.impl.OLEBatchProcessAdhocStep - Error while running Batch Process Step::OLEBatchProcessAdhocStep
java.lang.Exception: Batch process Failed
    at org.kuali.ole.batch.impl.AbstractBatchProcess.process(AbstractBatchProcess.java:123)
    at org.kuali.ole.batch.impl.OLEBatchProcessAdhocStep.executeBatch(OLEBatchProcessAdhocStep.java:50)
    at org.kuali.ole.batch.impl.OLEBatchProcessAdhocStep.execute(OLEBatchProcessAdhocStep.java:30)
    at org.kuali.ole.sys.batch.Job.runStep(Job.java:175)
    at org.kuali.ole.sys.batch.Job.execute(Job.java:121)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.kuali.ole.batch.ingest.BatchProcessBibImport.processBatch(BatchProcessBibImport.java:90)
    at org.kuali.ole.batch.impl.AbstractBatchProcess.process(AbstractBatchProcess.java:87)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.kuali.ole.batch.helper.BatchBibImportHelper.processBibMarcRecord(BatchBibImportHelper.java:89)
    at org.kuali.ole.batch.helper.BatchBibImportHelper.processBatch(BatchBibImportHelper.java:70)
    at org.kuali.ole.batch.ingest.BatchProcessBibImport.processBatch(BatchProcessBibImport.java:152)
    at org.kuali.ole.batch.ingest.BatchProcessBibImport.processBatch(BatchProcessBibImport.java:83)
    ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 3):

The line from which that that error is coming from suggests that the Batch Profile you are using has not been set up correctly in the database (specifically, it can't find the matching profile).  One definitive indicator would be a stack trace output in `catalina.out` involving the `getMatchingProfileObj` method in the `org.kuali.ole.batch.bo.OLEBatchProcessProfileBo` class.

If you migrated your application code over top of an existing database without having fully migrated the data in that database correctly, this problem could result.  Given that your question illustrates you used 1.5.0-M2 previously, which is  a pre-release milestone, you are better off re-initializing your database and reloading your data before running batch processes with a new version of the OLE codebase.

If you already did that, then this may be fodder for a bug report.

Answer (score 2):

Note that there were a lot of changes to the match/overlay part of the profiles in 1.5.2. You might want to look at how it is set up and make sure the choices apply.  Match and overlay was added for holdings and items and is being tested, this makes for more complicated possible choices. YOu could try setting it to no match, just add the bib and see if that works. As long as your file is utf8, not MARC8 encoding it shoul dload